# PHP Calendar, sum weekly hours and echo one by one

Tags: php, mysql

I need help on how to group my QUERY output by week.

The current output looks like this:
[image]

What I want:

I'd like it to sum all the columns that contain the same week number and hours into one column.

My current QUERY:

```
$query = "
SELECT userhours_id, user_hours, hours_timeoccur, SUM(user_hours) as 'myhours' FROM hours h 
where h.userhours_id = $loginuser_id 
AND h.hours_timeoccur = '$datetime'
";
```

I did try add the following to group it by $datetime which is each days number in 20xx-xx-xx format but it didn't make any difference:

```
GROUP BY WEEK(WEEKOFYEAR(h.hours_timeoccur))
```

I also tried to add an PHP IF statement which said if $weeknum (which is the week of each date), but I never really figured out what parameters I would be use.. so got stuck in this:

```
if ($weeknum = $weeknum ) {
 'myoutput'
}
```

Any idéa on how to accomplish this kind of request? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample table data and expected output. Question is unclear currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give the data grouped by user and year week:

```
SELECT userhours_id, WEEKOFYEAR(h.hours_timeoccur) AS hours_week, SUM(user_hours) as 'myhours' 
FROM hours h 
WHERE h.userhours_id = $loginuser_id 
GROUP BY userhours_id, hours_week
```

I removed the date where clause as if you only select for one date then it would not show useful information, maybe it would be best to provide a date range and query `BETWEEN`?